# How to Use Distinct() and Sum() in Single Query in Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Here I have 2 Columns like 
Id,Quantity. I want get the Distinct Id and its Quantity Sum in LINQ.
 I tried like this

```
var r = list.Where(some operation)
            .Select(x => x.Id)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(x => (int?)x.Quantity))
            .Sum();
```

Here at x.Quantity I got error..how can I solve this..
please give your suggestions

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error 40 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Quantity' and no extension method 'Quantity' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume that Id is int and Quantity is string, then you can use aggregate also. Below is one example:

```
class TestClass
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }
}

class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myclass = new TestClass[]
            {
                new TestClass {I = 1, S = "1"}, new TestClass { I = 1, S = "11" }, new TestClass { I = 1, S = "111" },
                new TestClass {I = 2, S = "2"},new TestClass {I = 2, S = "222"},new TestClass {I = 2, S = "2"},
                new TestClass {I = 3, S = "3"},new TestClass {I = 3, S = "333"},new TestClass {I = 3, S = "33"},
                new TestClass {I = 4, S = "44"},new TestClass {I = 4, S = "4"},
                new TestClass {I = 5, S = "5"}
            };

            var filteredObject = myclass.GroupBy(x => x.I).Select(y => new
            {
                I = y.Key,
                S = y.Select(z => z.S).Aggregate((a, b) => (Convert.ToInt32(a) + Convert.ToInt32(b)).ToString())
            });

            filteredObject.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.I + "    " + x.S));
        }

    }
```

Result is like:

1    123

2    226

3    369

4    48

5    5

Press any key to continue . . .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Group by Id.  Than you can do :

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
.Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Sum(y => (int?)y.Quantity) });
```

Comment: I've reformatted and made a correction.. There is no `Value` in the result of `GroupBy`

Comment: Still Error is Displayed

Comment: @benz You have to keep only the `var r = list.Where(some operation)` part of your code, remove everything else, and add the code shown in this response.

Comment: class.Quantity = list.Where(x => x.StatusId == (int)Enum.Attached  && x.StatusID != 3).GroupBy(x=>x.JobId).Select(x=>new{x.Key,x.Sum(y=>(int?)y.Quantity)});

Comment: Why would you cast quantity to a nullable int?

Comment: (int?) takes nulls also